# error at runserver of flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Source code is in book and in the code there are no errors.Why an error has happened?

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_script import Manager

app = Flask(__name__)

manager = Manager(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/user/<name>')
def user(name):
    return render_template('user.html', name=name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

in user.html

```
<h1>Hello, {{ name }}!</h1>
```

[this is screen of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtpTG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note the "address already in use" error: you're trying to setup a server on a port that's already in use. Either kill the previous server (which is using the port) OR run this one on a different port